# Send username and password to another site

Tags: php, api, authentication, autologin

I have two websites I want to connect through one login page on the master site.

You login in example1.com and on the settings i want to select "connect to example2.net automatically" I enter the user name and password and submit this to example2.net so the username and password is sent over

How would I do this?

Next whenever I am logged into example1.com and click access to example2.net i only want to send a username and API key over so its automatically logged in.

How would i do this?

Comment: Store the username and password in a session variable or you could store them in a cookie and send it over.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Which of these would you say is most secure? also what kind of command would i use to actually send it over site?

Comment: use CURL to post the login details to example2.net. read the php docs for more info. if you get stuck show some code and we'll work it out

Comment: [This](http://www.jasny.net/articles/simple-single-sign-on-for-php/) is a very good start.

Comment: IMO the best thing is to handle the login operations in one master domain. As described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510049/cross-domain-login-what-to-store-in-the-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick algorithm

1. User logs in to `site1.com` and activates Single-Sign-On (maybe a checkbox).
2. `site1.com` will create a database entry for that option.
3. User visits `site2.com` and if not already logged in he will be redirected to `site1.com/cross-authenticate.php` for example.
4. `site1.com` will have access to the cookie/session.
5. If the user has activated the Single-Sign-On option, `site1.com` will generate a token (maybe `base64` a very large and securely generated number) and stores it in the database.
6. `site1.com` will redirect the user to `site2.com/cross-authenticate.php?key=fnapsoufhapoer8hwf9ehrgdosughpa9dhg9aer8gyesrg` for example.
7. `site2.com` will check the database for that key, authenticate the user then start a valid session.

Comment: Thanks @Adnan. Simple and very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Save the `$_SESSION` and such in a database. Then check if the connection option from one site to the other is **SET**. If so, when the user uses the other website, query the database (against a username or whatnot). If the entry exists, create cookies & sessions based on the database values, otherwise re-route the user back to login page.

Comment: Bad idea. Very bad idea! How are you planning to authenticate the user on the second site? By username?

Comment: @Adnan i dont know how his website is structured. Obviously it wouldn't just be by `username` (thats just the simpliest example I could think of)

Comment: I'm authenticating through username and API key.